# Designing image gallery in xamarin.forms

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms

I have a JSON which contains image thumbnail URLS and some text now I have to render it as image gallery like phone gallery. I researched a lot about grid layout but didn't find a way to dynamically create numbers of grid of fixed width and height which can show images. Can any one tell me what will the best component to design gallery type page containing numbers of images?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [this](https://www.nuget.org/packages/DLToolkit.Forms.Controls.FlowListView/) nuget package and display Image in grid. Sample code for that:

```
<flv:FlowListView FlowColumnCount="3" SeparatorVisibility="None" HasUnevenRows="false"
FlowItemTappedCommand="{Binding ItemTappedCommand}" 
FlowItemsSource="{Binding PhotosList}" >
            <flv:FlowListView.FlowColumnTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackLayout>
                        <Image Source="{Binding Image}" HeightRequest="50" WidthRequest="50"/>
                        <Label Text="{Binding Name}" TextColor="Black" FontSize="Medium" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" HorizontalOptions="Fill" />
                    </StackLayout>
                </DataTemplate>
          </flv:FlowListView.FlowColumnTemplate>
</flv:FlowListView>
```

Where PhotosList will be your list of your Url and Text.

Answer (score 0):

There is a gallery control in Xamarin.Droid
Please see the sample -http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/user_interface/gallery/

If this is not what you are looking for then You can use your own [Listview](http://iosapi.xamarin.com/?link=T%3AXamarin.Forms.ListView) with images. And onseletion you can show the full image. 
See sample of list view with images in xamarin.form examples.

If you need multiple column use stack layout in horizontal rendering and inside that list views, probably 3.

That will give you 3 columns and unlimited scrollable rows.

**EDIT :** 
You have to create a ViewModel that would have a class with public properties that you want to bind to. Deserialize your JSON into an IEnumerable of this ViewModel class and bind to your listview. 
Inside the [Listview](http://iosapi.xamarin.com/?link=T%3AXamarin.Forms.ListView) you have to use [ImageCell](http://iosapi.xamarin.com/?link=T%3AXamarin.Forms.ImageCell)

For Creating an image since you have mentioned it to be from an URL, the following syntax would help you:

```
  webImage.Source = new UriImageSource {
    Uri = new Uri("http://xamarin.com/content/images/pages/forms/example-app.png"),
    CachingEnabled = true,
    CacheValidity = new TimeSpan(5,0,0,0)
};
```

The [employee example](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/introduction-to-xamarin-forms/#Customizing_the_Appearance_of_a_Cell) binds a `ListView` with one image and 2 `labels`.

```
class EmployeeCell : ViewCell
{
    public EmployeeCell()
    {
        var image = new Image
                    {
                        HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Start
                    };
        image.SetBinding(Image.SourceProperty, new Binding("ImageUri"));
        image.WidthRequest = image.HeightRequest = 40;

        var nameLayout = CreateNameLayout();

        var viewLayout = new StackLayout()
                         {
                             Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal,
                             Children = { image, nameLayout }
                         };
        View = viewLayout;
    }    
}
```

**EDIT 2 :**
In case you have variable number of image URLs to be rendered then you will be better off going for a [TableView](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/working-with/tableview/). TableView isnt bound to a datasource and you can create individual cells as per your requirement by parsing the JSON object. 
ie :  Each JSON object would be a `TableSection` and each Image would be a `ImageCell`

Comment: yeah i can understand what you told but in the listview i can bind only one object of json in a cell how can i bind multible objects data in a single cell.

Comment: The Gallery control is for Android only, not Xamarin Forms

Comment: @Rohit - Every object of my JSON contains an image url, image title and date of capturing the image, when I bind the JSON to list view only single object's data can be rendered on row by row but when a row contains two images and detail behind those , How is it possible to bind two JSON object in single row at same time?

Comment: Do you mean your JSON object have multiple URLs?

Comment: @Rohit - No single URL but show multiple URL on each row.

Comment: I dont really understand what you meant. You can create as many cells as you want in the TableSection. If that is not what you are looking for then please post a sample JSON and your desired out put.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up splitting my source JSON array into 3 columns using this code

```
return myGroupedGalleryDto.Select ((row, index) => new {row, index})
                    .GroupBy (g => g.index / 3, i => i.row)
                    .Select ((v, k) => new GalleryDto () {
                    Key = k,
                    Images = v.ToList ()
                }).ToList ();
```

and then in XAML,

```
<Grid x:Name="grid">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Image Grid.Column="0" Source="{Binding Images[0].MyImageUrl}" />
    <Image Grid.Column="1" Source="{Binding Images[1].MyImageUrl}" />
    <Image Grid.Column="2" Source="{Binding Images[2].MyImageUrl}" />
</Grid>
```

Using the following ViewModels

```
public class GalleryDto
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public string MyImageUrl { get; set; }
}

public class GroupedGalleryDto
{
    public int Key { get; set; }

    public List<GalleryDto> Images { get; set; }
}
```